# compile project(:somelibrary) { exclude group: 'com.google.guava' } function exclude not found?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I imported project a library in Android Studio, but am not able to exclude a group because gradle does not find that exclude method method when the compile directive is on an included project?

It can find exclude for the following method

```
      compile('xyc.com.whatever'){exclude 'com.google.guava'}
```

but not for:

```
   compile project(:somelibrary) { exclude group: 'com.google.guava' }
```

this exclude method is not available for included project?  what gives? How can I exclude this group?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try:

```
compile( project(:somelibrary) ){
    exclude group:'com.google.guava'
}
```

Notice the extra parens. In your case, the closure is associated with `project` rather than `compile`.